# 'core' is not a registered namespace Django

Tags: python, django

It is the first time i get this error while trying to create a slug. Can't seem to find out why and there's no other answer in here. Answer edited with the urls.

Here is the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default="Sport")
    slug = models.SlugField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:productpage", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
        })
```

Here is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

def index(request):
    context = {'items': Item.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/index.html', context) #returns the index.html template

def shop(request):
    context = {'items': Item.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/shop.html', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/about.html')

def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/blog.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/contact.html')

def productpage(request):
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/product-single.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('shop/', views.shop, name="shop"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name="blog"),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('product-single/<slug>/', views.productpage, name="productpage")
]
```

Thank you for answers and help!

Comment: where does core come from did you set namespace, show us your URLs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: already edited answer with urls

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` you need to specify a [namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) like so:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'core' # This is the namespace so you can reverse urls with core:*

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('shop/', views.shop, name="shop"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name="blog"),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('product-single/<slug>/', views.productpage, name="productpage")
]
```